# FormApp.openById not working when i'm not collaborator

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a script that reads specific emails and retrieves data from them to create responses on a google form.
It is working as a charm when I have a collaborator access to the form, but it throw me this error message when I'm not...
"No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it"

```
var logEnvironment = "TEST";  // TEST for Testing environment, PRODUCTION for production

  // Get Ids for the Google Form and Response Spreadsheet
  if (logEnvironment == "TEST") {
    var premediaFormId = <MY TEST FORM ID>
    var responseWorkbookId = *******;
  } else {
    var premediaFormId = <MY PRODUCTION FORM ID>;
    var responseWorkbookId = *******;
  }

  // Google Form

  var premediaForm = FormApp.openById(premediaFormId);
  var premediaFormItems = premediaForm.getItems();
```

On the production form, I can't give access to everybody running the script as collaborators.. they should have only regular access to create responses.. but we don't want the users to be entering the responses manually if we already have an email from a system with all the information.

Integrating the system with the form is out of the question.

Is there a way to resolve this access issue....